# How to refresh a ListActivity within a TabView?

Tags: android, listview, listactivity, tabactivity, tabview

The tab activity queries the database and binds the result to the list view.

The problems is when i clicked on the delete button, it works but the list view did not refresh.

the things i've tried:

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
adapter.notifyDataSetInvalidated();
listview.invalidateViews();
listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

so far none is working, i have to click another tab (tab1) then click back (tab2) to refresh it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note sure about the way you are using to delete. I think you are manipulating ListView directly. You have to use `remove()` method of adapter. In fact you have to manipulate the contents of the list through the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You should use this on delete button click:

```
((EfficientAdapter)listview.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
```

where EfficientAdapter is your Adapter class.

Hope this will work for you...:)